# Property 'email' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am very new to typescrypt, and I'm currently in the process of migrating a project from JS to TS.
While I was changing some things on my server endpoints, an error appeared:

```
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'string | JwtPayload'
```

This is my code so far:

```
try {
    const token = await TokenController.getTokenFromRequest(req);
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
    const user = await AuthController.getUserByMail(decoded.username); // <- Error appears here
    res.json(user);
} catch (error: any) {
    ErrorController.errorCallback(error, res);
}
```

Edit: My code for 'getUserByMail' looks like so:

```
static async getUserByMail(email: string, includePassword = false) {
   let query = User.findOne({
       email: email
   });

   if (!includePassword) {
       query.select('-password');
   }

   return query.exec();
}
```

I know that the error happens because I'm trying to access a property that `string` doesn't have. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show `getUserByMail`

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403905/how-to-add-additional-properties-to-jwtpayload-type-from-types-jsonwebtoken?

Answer (score 0):

Create global.d.ts:

```
// global.d.ts
declare module "jsonwebtoken" {
    export interface JwtPayload {
        //make optional so when you try to decode stuff other than user it will show it can be undefined
        email?: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me an ```Property 'decode' does not exist on type 'typeof import("jsonwebtoken")'``` error on my ```jwt.decode()``` function